# How to change password using script

Tags: shell-script, password, nis

```
#OUTFILE=out.xml
prefix='EDSAD150'
password="asdf1234"
pass=$(perl -e 'print crypt($ARGV[0], "asdf1234")' $password)

for i in {01..02};do

    usname=$prefix""$i
    yes $pass | yppasswd $usname

done
```

I want to change the password of the users but when I run this script I have to give the server password every time because I am using`yppasswd` command . But when I used `passwd` command the NIS files won't change.

Comment: What distribution are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Use `chpasswd` command to change the password using script

```
root@SHW:cat password.list
user1:pass1
user2:pass2
user3:pass3

root@SHW:chpasswd < password.list
```

Above example illustrate an example of given command to change password of users namely user1,user2,user3.

Comment: the chpasswd is not Working 
 $usname:$pass|chpasswd

Comment: @Ann "not working" doesn't tell us anything. You need to explain exactly how it fails. Is there an error message? No error but the password is unchanged? Some passwords changed but problems with the NIS?

Comment: changepwUser1.sh: line 9: EDSAD15001:asbTyBDRLWRmQ: command not found
changepwUser1.sh: line 9: EDSAD15002:asbTyBDRLWRmQ: command not found
**this the error I am getting** the list of  the user  is generating along with password when the script  is running

Comment: @Ann and what are you running? We don't have access to yours scripts, please edit your question and show us what you did exactly.

Comment: Have you tried above script with your existing username/password pair ?

Comment: Yes @SHW I have Tried it... when Run script only changing the command in the loop as $usname:$pass|chpasswd I got a error as I gave mentioned above

Comment: @Ann Can you paste here your script ?
Error message occur on 9th line. What about first 8 lines ?
Have you had executed this script with root privilege ?

Comment: @SHW this is the whole script,there is no problem with 8th line.........

Comment: Better you paste your modified script here